# UNIX/Python - How to use cx_Oracle without internet and pip

Tags: python, oracle, python-import, cx-oracle

My company does not (yet) allow us to install or upgrade python3 neither install modules from pip on their servers. Even if I could, the machine is not connected to internet. But we can execute the python2 binary

## Goal

Use the `cx_Oracle` module without using `pip` and internet

## Workaround tentative

I got the idea to install cx_Oracle package on my computer and then copy the module files installed from my computer to the server.

So server dev folder looks like this (only listing interesting directories and files, omitting `__pychache__`, `*.pyc` and other useless `*.py` files):

```
|-- test_cx_oracle_in_local.py
\-- sqlalchemy/
    |-- connectors
    |-- databases
    |-- dialects
    |   |-- firebird
    |   |-- mysql
    |   |-- mssql
    |   |-- oracle
    |   |   |-- base.py
    |   |   |-- cx_oracle.py   <--- This is the interesting file
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   \-- zxjdbc.py
    |   |-- postgresql
    |   |-- sqlite
    |   |-- sybase
    |-- engine
    |-- event
    |-- ext
    |   \-- declarative
    |-- orm
    |-- pool
    |-- sql
    |-- testing
    |   |-- plugin
    |   \-- suite
    \-- util
```

---

### TEST 1

```
import cx_Oracle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cx_Oracle.connect(user="xxxxxxxx", password="xxxxxxxx", dns="xxxxxxxx")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cx_oracle_in_local.py", line xx, in <module>
    import cx_oracle
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

---

### TEST 2

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.cx_oracle import cx_Oracle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cx_Oracle.connect(user="xxxxxxxx", password="xxxxxxxx", dns="xxxxxxxx")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cx_oracle_in_local.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.connection = cx_oracle.connect(user="xxxxxxxx", password="xxxxxxxx", dns="xxxxxxxx")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

---

### TEST 3

Using [STACKOVERFLOW - Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

```
import os, sys, inspect
sys.path.insert(0, xxxxxxxx) # <--- see link above to see sorin's answer
import cx_oracle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("SYS_PATH = " + str(sys.path))
    cx_Oracle.connect(user="xxxxxxxx", password="xxxxxxxx", dns="xxxxxxxx")
```

Output:

```
SYS_PATH = ['/xxxxxxxx/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle', '/xxxxxxxx/sqlalchemy/dialects', '/xxxxxxxx/sqlalchemy', 'xxxxxxxx', ...]
  File "test_cx_oracle_in_local.py", line xx, in <module>
    import cx_oracle
  File "/xxxxxxxx/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/cx_oracle.py", line 286, in <module>
    from . import base as oracle
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

---

## Please notice

- The server OS is `UNIX` family (**not** a Windows/MAC)
- I do not have edition neither execution rights to `/bin`, `/usr`, `/opt`, etc.
- I can't use `pip`, `pip` is not even installed on the server
- I can download files from my pro computer to the server
- From server side, pinging or getting internet is impossible
- I am currently running with `python 2` but I am interested for `python 3` solution if you have

## Question

How can I fully use the module `cx_Oracle` without internet and without using `pip` neither having `+wx` access to system folder?

Comment: If your company has that strict of a policy regarding software installations, you should make sure you have the permission of the system admin and security admin to be doing what you're doing. This feels a lot like trying to circumvent an "Acceptable Use" user policy; people get fired for less...

Comment: Oh it could xD But not. in fact it is more an issue for "upgrading" the server because there are currently other emergencies and things planned. Upgrading python is (almost) the last priority. In fact we have it on other servers, but not on this one :( Also this is why I am interested in Python3 answer because this machine should be upgraded "by soon" (meaning in 1 or 2 years....)

Comment: [install using github](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#install-using-github) clone the repo in ur system, and in server, then install by python setup.py as mention in link

Comment: Mac runs Unix. What Unix? Solaris, HP-UX, AIX?

Comment: @sahasrara62 : ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources```
:(

Comment: You can download the package manually, then run package's setup.py and then this setup has also some option like 'install --user' where the final python module is then installed in your home directory. So basically you can manually duplicate all steps `pip` does. (Maybe it would be easier with some older version of cx_Oracle)

Comment: After you solve the problem of `cx_Oracle` absence the next step will be to get Oracle client, that [is required for cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#oracle-client-and-oracle-database-interoperability). Also you may read the documentation of this module, where they describe all [possible ways](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#install-using-source-from-pypi) to install the module. To break the security policy you may also build portable version of Python 3 and instal regular cx_Oracle module here.

Comment: You could also install that environment on a container if you are allowed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cx_oracle.py` file in the `sqlalchemy` folder is not actually the cx_Oracle library - it's just a sqlalchemy wrapper for the actual cx_Oracle library, which is a compiled binary (including the compiled ODPI-C library, written in C).

Easiest way I can think of:

1. [Download cx_Oracle-7.3.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/7.3.0/#files) - this is the Wheel for the Python 2.7 version of cx_Oracle 7.3, the most recent cx_Oracle to support Python 2.
2. Extract it (it's just a zip file) and put `cx_Oracle.so` somewhere on your server. This is the binary cx_Oracle library file.
3. Load it as a relative library - if it's in the same directory as your code, `import cx_Oracle` should work.

Comment: And it worked !! you are awesome. However, I had to choose cx_Oracle-7.3.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (with the `mu` , not `m`) and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much , it really works, in python 3.* too.